NetSuite Sales Order Creation - Change Subsidiary Selection
In NetSuite, the default behavior for creating transactions (like sales orders) is to select the customer first, followed by the subsidiary. Is there any way we can change this - Select subsidiary first and then customers based on the subsidiary selection? I appreciate any help on this. Thanks.
NetSuite Customization or the way to handle this.
